# Checking my understanding regarding the difference between Terminal and Shell

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, terminal, shell

I am trying to test my understanding regarding the difference between terminal and shell. The terminal is just a text-based interface in which it accepts commands from the user. Moreover, the terminal executes the shell. The shell is a command-line interpreter. That is , it is responsible for converting the commands into a form to be executed by the OS, so it is literally an interpreter for the commands. There are many types of shells, such as Bourne Shell (`sh`)and Bourne Again Shell (`bash`) which is an extended version of the `sh`. In general, every shell flavor has its own features, they have very similar syntax if they conform to a standard such as `POSIX`. Is that correct ? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Ya got it pal :-) https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-terminal-console-shell-and-command-line/

Comment: Thank you guys :)

Comment: [This is a terminal](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100). It has a screen and keyboard, but no brains. It's a combined input/output device. You're talking about terminal emulators - software equivalents of this device. This distinction may be overly pedantic in everyday life, but since you want to have a good understanding it could be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Moreover, the terminal executes the shell

Yes, that's true in general, assuming you're talking about the "terminal emulator" apps.

(They're called that way because they emulate *physical* terminals, and those didn't execute the shell – they connected to a computer that ran one, sort of like how PuTTY is a terminal emulator that doesn't run any shell locally, it just connects to remote computers via SSH.)

Though it's worth mentioning that Windows is somewhat of an exception, where originally it used to be the opposite – in Windows, you would directly start a shell such as Cmd.exe (or any other console-based .exe file) and the system would automatically pop up a 'Conhost' console window for it, which could not be started manually. (The point here being that Cmd.exe is a shell, not a terminal, and the Windows behavior is a common source of confusion.)

This did change somewhat with the Windows console system rework done as part of creating the new "Windows Terminal" app (which brought various concepts such as pseudo-tty over from Unix): the original behavior remains but now you *can* start Windows Terminal and it'll then run the shell, like you would expect.

> The shell is a command-line interpreter. That is , it is responsible for converting the commands into a form to be executed by the OS, so it is literally an interpreter for the commands. There are many types of shells, such as Bourne Shell (sh)and Bourne Again Shell (bash) which is an extended version of the sh. In general, every shell flavor has its own features, they have very similar syntax if they conform to a standard such as POSIX. Is that correct ? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Yes, although there is a much greater variety of shells than just Bourne/POSIX-style; shells don't have to conform to POSIX – for example, csh/tcsh were *very* widely used in the past (csh predates Bash by a decade and has a syntax very different from Bourne), Fish seems to be rather popular these days, not to mention PowerShell and Cmd.exe on Windows, DCL on VMS, and similar.

Only the specific shell located at `/bin/sh` is required to be POSIX-compliant (if the system as a whole aims for some level of POSIX compliance in the first place). So it's rather common e.g. for BSDs to default to a non-POSIX shell such as tcsh for interactive use, while still including a POSIX-compliant shell at /bin/sh for use with scripts.

Comment: Shells don't necessarily have to be program launchers, too. Eg. "serious business" routers have special shells that are used to configure the device.